# Audio Video synchronisation with Libav encoder

Tags: java, encoding, video-encoding, libav

I am trying to encode live rtmp stream via Libav library encoder by using avconv tool in following command -

```
avconv -timelimit 4000 -i  rtmp://IP/live/file-name -shortest -s 176*144 -r 10 \
-b:v 56k -ab 12k -ac 1 -ar 22050 -f flv  rtmp://IP/live/file-name_56
```

But audio is not synchronized with video in output stream, and video lags behind as its bit rate has been changed to 56 kbps.  But audio bit rate doesn't change & current audio is audible.

I am playing it via Run Time Environment in Java and 1 hour video stops after 10 mins. This issue is there when I am running a thread in java to run avconv command as follows

```
public void run() {
    try{
         Thread.sleep(500);
 Process pr=  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("avconv -timelimit 4000  -i  rtmp://IP/live/file-name  -shortest -s 176*144  -r 10 -b:v 56k -ab 12k -ac 1 -ar 22050 -f flv  rtmp://IP/live/file-name_56");
pr.waitFor();
}}
```

Kindly provide suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0):

Audio synchronization is achieved by

**-async samples_per_second**

Audio sync method. "Stretches/squeezes" the audio stream to match the timestamps, the parameter is the maximum samples per second by which the audio is changed. -async 1 is a special case where only the start of the audio stream is corrected without any later correction.

```
Process pr=  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("avconv -async 15 -timelimit 4000  -i  rtmp://IP/live/file-name  -shortest -s 176*144  -r 10 -b:v 56k -ab 12k -ac 1 -ar 22050 -f flv  rtmp://IP/live/file-name_56");
```